# High pitch noise while monitor is off and several attemps for screen to load

Tags: display, graphics-card

I have a 24" Samsung SyncMaster 225 monitor which has started causing issues lately.

1. When the power is off it emits a very high pitch noise. When I turn it on it goes away. I thought this might be a cable issue since my cat likes to chew on cables sometimes, so I replaced the cable and still have the issue.
2. When I turn the monitor off, getting it back "on" again takes several attempts. What I mean by that is, I'll see my desktop flicker, then go away. I have to power on/power off between 10-20 times before it finally "catches".

I haven't used this monitor on another computer yet, but was wondering if this is most likely a monitor issue or possibly a video card issue? My video card is fairly new and top of the line.

UPDATE:
I just plugged my monitor into my Mac Mini and it worked fine. So is this basically a video card that is failing? The video card is an [ASUS nvidia GTX 680](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121705)

Comment: So was the high pitched noise (often refered to as coil whine, could be capacitor whine also) actually comming from the video card?  Coils and caps and a few other high pitched switching frequency whines are usually the power aspects of things.

Comment: I'm not sure where it's coming from. It sounds like the monitor.

Comment: That is just confusing how you get the monitor to work, when it sounded like it is about to have a failure. You have 2 numbered items in the Question, when you switched the monitor to a different computer, No more whine, and no more switch-on problems at all?